# FileNotFoundException in Solr 8.9

Tags: java, indexing, solr

I am working to index the word documents on solr8.9, but occur error FileNotFoundException and failed.
So, I tested other versions, confirmed one fact that all versions after 8.3.1 occur the same error.

This is a command used.

```
java -Dc=gettingstarted -Dhost=localhost -Dport=8983 -Dauto -jar post.jar "test.docx"
```

[image].

Comment: You probably haven't enabled the extracting request handler. Add the required libs to the `lib` directive in `solrconfig.xml`. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#configuring-the-extractingrequesthandler-in-solrconfig-xml for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 8.9 is very bad for me, so I use 7.7. Let me check and ping you.

Comment: It's the same procedure. Just replace 8_9 with 7_7 in the url: https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#configuring-the-extractingrequesthandler-in-solrconfig-xml